# Exceeded geocode limits error when using file_get_contents()

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, geocode

I am trying to get lat long of address provided in my web panel using

```
 file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' 
. $formattedAddr . '&sensor=false),
```

but getting this response-
"error_message" :

```
"You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
```

Above same link is working fine(giving correct response) on hitting directly in url. Please suggest me what to do?
I am using php.

Comment: I believe you can pay for more access, the other way is to get a database of your own with the Lat and Long data in it and just use Haversine or a derivative for the calculations.  We use a US database of zipcode data with GEO locations, for example.  There are of course a few things you could do that violate googles TOS agreement, but I'm not a liberty to discuss that.

Comment: You have to apply an API key in your request. Now you don't apply it, so you are using a shared quota with other users. Create your project and get an API key as explained in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

Comment: Resolved problem using API key. Thanks @xomena